# will i have to call the applet from the main class?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, applet, program-entry-point

I started a new JApplet project in my Netbeans IDE . While selecting a new project i selected *swing GUI forms* that  contained JApplet.After the project initialization was over i see a `main class` i.e a class that contains the main method.Because i had to do the designing for the applet i  selected another JApplet GUI form  . Now how to call this form from the main class ? Why is the class with the main method created when i am working with the applets ?

[image]

the class containing the main method is automatically created when i start a new JApplet project in my netbeans IDE.

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson It would have been great if you tried to answer this question

Answer (score 2):

You don't call applets from a class with a main method. Applets are loaded by a browser. Applications are invoked by using the main() method. Read the [Swing Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). There are sections on:

1. How to Make Applets
2. How to Make Frames

which should help you understand the difference.

Comment: i know this. please see the edit. when i click the run project button in my IDE it first works with the main class and b'coz main class contains nothing it finishes as soon as it  loads.